# Unable to install Xubuntu 16.04: "not a typewriter"

Tags: system-installation, usb, xubuntu

I've been trying to install Xubuntu 16.04 i386 on a netbook with an Intel Atom N270 2GB Ram and 250 GB HDD using a USB stick. 
Currently I'm using ElementaryOS, which I installed without problems, but now I'm trying with Xubuntu and I get the following after getting the Xubuntu screen at the start:

```
stdin: not a typewriter 
Generating locales (this might take a while...)
Generation complete
pwconv: failed to change the mode of /etc/passwd- to 0600
chfn: PAM: Authentication failure
adduser '/usr/bin/chfn -f Live session user xubuntu' returned error code 1. Exiting
Using CD-ROM mount point /cdrom/
Identifying... [e4c48fb5262dbf5a174c170d397f5c6a-2]
Scanning disc for index files...
Found 4 package indexes, 0 source indexes, 0 translation indexes
Found label 'Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release i386 (20160719)
Copying package lists... gpgv: Signature made Tue Jul 19 21:13:51 2016 UTC using DSA key ID FBB75451
 gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>"
Reading package indexes... Done
Writing new source list
 Source list entries for disc are:
deb cdrom: [Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release i386 (20160719)]/ xenial main multiverse restricted universe
Repeat this process for the rest of the CDs in your set
```

I've created the live USB with unetbootin and startup disk creator, changed USB sticks and I'm still getting the same message. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does it start? I don't really see anything fatal there.

Comment: The Xubuntu screen appears as if it was loading but it just stays there. Options like "Install Xubuntu" or "Try Xubuntu" never show up.

Comment: I would try redownloading the image then.

Comment: Already tried. From different mirrors. Still not working.

Comment: Actually `not a typewriter` is not the main problem and it is actually good that Xubuntu didn't recognize the computer as `Typewriter`

Comment: Yep, so have you got any suggestions? Which is supposed to be the main problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, looks like I finally fixed it. Instead of 16.04 iso I downloaded 14.04 and it worked. The live usb started perfectly and I installed xubuntu successfully.